# I need to create XML-PRC compatible Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, xml-rpc, jax-rpc

In Netbeans 8.0 I created Web Service (without certification), which is woking on SOAP. But SOAP protocol is incompatible with its, what demands prepared remote client. I changed in WSDL protocol from "document" to "rpc", but still it not enogh and application server issues errors:

```
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
```

SEVERE:   WSITPVD0035: Error in Verifying Security in Inbound Message.
com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {}methodCall

Do you know anybody how to properly develop web service under this old technology?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody gives me advice to look on this page. https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/server.html If I will be successfull, I will report here.

Answer (score 0):

For rpc style bindings you can take a look at axis project which is  JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant. More here: http://axis.apache.org/axis/

Comment: Unfortunatelly, those pages (http://axis.apache.org/axis/) goes to empty or forwarder links.

Comment: It strange, I get the axis page directly.